# Understanding a recursively defined list (fibs in terms of zipWith)

Tags: list, haskell, lazy-evaluation, fibonacci, lazy-sequences

I'm learning Haskell, and came across the following code:

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

which I'm having a bit of trouble parsing, in terms of how it works. It's very neat, I understand that nothing more is needed, but I'd like to understand how Haskell manages to "fill in" fibs when I write:

```
take 50 fibs
```

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 123, accepted):

I'll give a bit of an explanation of how it works internally. First, you must realise that Haskell uses a thing called a [thunk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk_%28functional_programming%29) for its values. A thunk is basically a value that has not yet been computed yet -- think of it as a function of 0 arguments. Whenever Haskell wants to, it can evaluate (or partly-evaluate) the thunk, turning it in to a real value. If it only *partly* evaluates a thunk, then the resulting value will have more thunks in it.

For example, consider the expression:

```
(2 + 3, 4)
```

In an ordinary language, this value would be stored in memory as `(5, 4)`, but in Haskell, it is stored as `(<thunk 2 + 3>, 4)`. If you ask for the second element of that tuple, it will tell you "4", without ever adding 2 and 3 together. Only if you ask for the first element of that tuple will it evaluate the thunk, and realise that it is 5.

With fibs, it's a bit more complicated, because it's recursive, but we can use the same idea. Because `fibs` takes no arguments, Haskell will permanently store any list elements that have been discovered -- that is important.

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

It helps to visualise Haskell's current knowledge of three expressions: `fibs`, `tail fibs` and `zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)`. We shall assume Haskell starts out knowing the following:

```
fibs                         = 0 : 1 : <thunk1>
tail fibs                    = 1 : <thunk1>
zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs) = <thunk1>
```

Note that the 2nd row is just the first one shifted left, and the 3rd row is the first two rows summed.

Ask for `take 2 fibs` and you'll get `[0, 1]`. Haskell doesn't need to further evaluate the above to find this out.

Ask for `take 3 fibs` and Haskell will get the 0 and 1, and then realise that it needs to *partly evaluate* the thunk. In order to fully evaluate `zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)`, it needs to sum the first two rows -- it can't fully do that, but it can *begin* to sum the first two rows:

```
fibs                         = 0 : 1 : 1: <thunk2>
tail fibs                    = 1 : 1 : <thunk2>
zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs) = 1 : <thunk2>
```

Note that I filled in the "1" in the 3rd row, and it automatically appeared in the first and second rows as well, since all three rows are sharing the same thunk (think of it like a pointer that got written to). And because it didn't finish evaluating, it created a new thunk containing the *rest* of the list, should that ever be needed.

It isn't needed, though, because `take 3 fibs` is done: `[0, 1, 1]`. But now, say you ask for `take 50 fibs`; Haskell already remembers the 0, 1 and 1. But it needs to keep going. So it continues summing the first two rows:

```
fibs                         = 0 : 1 : 1 : 2 : <thunk3>
tail fibs                    = 1 : 1 : 2 : <thunk3>
zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs) = 1 : 2 : <thunk3>
```

...

```
fibs                         = 0 : 1 : 1 : 2 : 3 : <thunk4>
tail fibs                    = 1 : 1 : 2 : 3 : <thunk4>
zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs) = 1 : 2 : 3 : <thunk4>
```

And so on, until it has filled in 48 columns of the 3rd row, and thus has worked out the first 50 numbers. Haskell evaluates just as much as it needs, and leaves the infinite "rest" of the sequence as a thunk object in case it ever needs any more.

Note that if you subsequently ask for `take 25 fibs`, Haskell will not evaluate it again -- it will just take the first 25 numbers from the list it has already calculated.

**Edit**: Added a unique number to each thunk to avoid confusion.

Comment: Hey, why does this work?
fibs                                  = 0 : 1 : 1 : 2 : <thunk>
tail fibs                            = 1 : 1 : 2 : <thunk>
zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs) = 1 : 2 : <thunk>

Shouldn't the last line ("result line") be like this:
zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs) = 1 : 2 : 3 : <thunk>
Because I can add 1 + 2. Why does it ccreate a new <thunk>?

And shouldn't this "result line" be appended to the original list (fibs)? Like this: 0 : 1 : 1 : 2 : 1 : 2 : 3 : <thunk> (last 4 values incl <thunk> are the result of zipwith (+) ...)

Sorry for all of those questions :x

Comment: And new lines apparently do not seem to work in comments.. Sorry about that too :/

Comment: Yeah the comment syntax is annoying. "Shouldn't the last line ... be ... Because I can add 1 + 2." -- ah but just because the runtime *can* do something in Haskell doesn't mean it *does*. That's the whole point of "lazy evaluation". I mean, eventually it will, but at that stage I'm just showing the computation for "take 4 fibs" which only needs to evaluate 2 elements of "zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)". I don't understand your other question; you don't append zipWith to fibs, you append it to 1:2 to make the final fibs.

Comment: Alright, sorry for the late answer, had to write some exams. I understand the "lazy evaluation" - it seems to be a pretty good idea :) Alright, so here is what I still don't understand, just take a look at this picture: https://imagebin.ca/v/3OcDpD9WiVpr (it is easier to visualize by using old-school pen & paper). I hope you can understand my problem by this image. Have a good day! :)

Comment: The problem with your picture is the statement "fibs = 0 : 1 : 1 : 2 : x" (where x is "zipWith ..."). That isn't the definition of fibs; it's defined as "fibs = 0 : 1 : x". I'm not sure where the extra ": 1 : 2" came from.

It's maybe because I wrote "zipWith ... = <thunk>" and then later I wrote "fibs = 0 : 1 : 1 : 2 : <thunk>". Is that it? Note that <thunk> is a different value in each block of code. Each time the thunk is evaluated, it is replaced with a new expression with a new thunk inside it. I will update the code to give each thunk a unique number.

Comment: Ah alright, thank you. Indeed, I was confused by the thunk. That you for your insights and help. Have a great day! :)

Answer (score 23):

I wrote an article  on this a while back. You can find it [here](http://blog.srinivasan.biz/software/fibonacci-numbers-the-slow-way-or-the-fast-and-lazy-way).

As I mentioned there, read chapter 14.2 in Paul Hudak's book "The Haskell School of Expression", where he talks about Recursive Streams, using Fibonacci example.

Note:tail of a sequence is the sequence without the first item.

```
|---+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+------------------------------------|
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |  5 |  8 | 13 | 21 | Fibonacci sequence (fibs)          |
|---+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+------------------------------------|
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 |  8 | 13 | 21 | 34 | tail of Fib sequence (tail fibs)   |
|---+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+------------------------------------|
```

Add the two columns: **add fibs (tail fibs)** to get **tail of tail of fib sequence**

```
|---+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+------------------------------------|
| 2 | 3 | 5 | 8 | 13 | 21 | 34 | 55 | tail of tail of Fibonacci sequence |
|---+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+------------------------------------|
```

add fibs (tail fibs) can be written as zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)

Now, all we need to do prime the generation by starting with the first 2 fibonacci numbers to get the complete fibonacci sequence.

1:1: zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)

Note: This recursive definition will not work in a typical language that does eager evaluation. It works in haskell as it does lazy evaluation. So, if you ask for the first 4 fibonacci numbers, *take 4 fibs*, haskell only computes enough of sequence as required.

Answer (score 3):

A very related example run through can be found [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell/Lazy_evaluation), although I haven't gone over it completely it maybe of some help.

I am not exactly sure of the implementation details, but I suspect they should be on the lines of my argument below.

Please take this with a pinch of salt, this maybe inaccurate implementationally but just as an understanding aid.

Haskell will not evaluate anything unless it is forced to, that is known as Lazy Evaluation, which is a beautiful concept in itself.

So lets assume we've been asked only to do a `take 3 fibs` Haskell stores the `fibs` list as `0:1:another_list`, since we've been asked to `take 3` we may as well assume it is stored as `fibs = 0:1:x:another_list` and `(tail fibs) = 1:x:another_list` and `0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)` will then be `0 : 1 : (0+1) : (1+x) : (x+head another_list) ...`

By pattern matching Haskell knows that `x = 0 + 1` So leading us to `0:1:1`.

I'll be really interested though if someone knows some proper implementational details. I can understand that Lazy Evaluation techniques can be fairly complicated though.

Hope this helps in understanding.

Mandatory disclaimer again : Please take this with a pinch of salt, this maybe inaccurate implementationally but just as an understanding aid.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at definition of **`zipWith`**

`zipWith f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : zipWith xs ys`

Our fibs is: 

`fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)`

For `take 3 fibs` substituting the definition of `zipWith` and `xs = tail (x:xs)` we get

`0 : 1 : (0+1) : zipWith (+) (tail fibs) (tail (tail fibs))`

For `take 4 fibs` substituting once more we get

`0 : 1 : 1 : (1+1) : zipWith (+) (tail (tail fibs)) (tail (tail (tail fibs)))`

and so on.