# map of all successors for each element in haskell

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

Given a sequence of elements, I want to find a list of all the *direct* successors for each element:

Example:

```
"AABAABAAC"
```

Should return something like (using `Data.Map`):

```
fromList [('A',"ABABA"), ('B',"AA"), ('C', "")]
```

I am aware of the `fromListWith` function but I can't seem to get the list comprehension right:

```
succs :: Ord a => [a] -> M.Map a [a]
succs xs = M.fromListWith (++) [(x, ???) | ??? ]
```

Comment: Why not is `ABAABAAC` successor of `A`? Where is `ABABA` successor for `A`? EDIT: ok, I understand but edit your question please. Write "for each repetition of"

Comment: I'm sorry for being unclear. I was thinking about **direct** successors. I think about the sequence as a sequence of states `A,B,C` and two neighboring states meaning a transition from one state to another. The sequence would be something like this: `A->A->B->A->A->B->A->A->C`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help?

```
succs xs@(_:xss) = M.fromListWith (++) $ zip xs (map (:[]) xss ++ [[]])
```

I think it returns `('A',"ABABAC")...`, your example has no `C`.

`(:[])` is a point-free version of

```
singleton :: a -> [a]
singleton x = [x]
```

---

How did I get to this solution? I find this definition for the fibonacci numbers fascinating: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273621/understanding-a-recursively-defined-list-fibs-in-terms-of-zipwith) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105765/generating-fibonacci-numbers-in-haskell)

```
fibs = fibs = 0:1:zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

A similar thing can pair up every element with its successor:

```
let x = "AABAABAAC"
zip x (tail x)
[('A','A'),('A','B'),('B','A'),('A','A'),('A','B'),('B','A'),('A','A'),('A','C')]
```

This type almost matches the input to

```
M.fromListWith :: Ord k => (a -> a -> a) -> [(k, a)] -> M.Map k a
```

Now turn the characters into singleton lists and add an empty list to not suppress `('C',"")`.

Comment: It returns `('A',"CABABA")...` due to how `fromListWith` applies the combining function. The order can be reversed by `flip`ing `(++)`. It can also be done by adding an `fmap reverse .`.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the problem into two parts. First, find the edges between two elements of a list.

```
edges :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
edges (x:y:zs) = (x,y):edges (y:zs)
edges _ = []
```

Then build a map to all the items that are the immediate successors of an item with `fromListWith`.

```
succs :: Ord a => [a] -> M.Map a [a]
succs = M.fromListWith (++) . map (\(x,y) -> (x,[y])) . edges
```

This doesn't give quite exactly what you desire. There's no entry for `'C'` since it has no immediate successors.

```
succs "AABAABAAC" = fromList [('A',"CABABA"),('B',"AA")]
```

Instead we can make a less general-purpose version of `edges` that includes an item for the last item in the list.

```
succs :: Ord a => [a] -> M.Map a [a]
succs = M.fromListWith (++) . edges
    where
        edges (x:y:zs) = (x,[y]):edges (y:zs)
        edges (x:zs)   = (x,[] ):edges zs
        edges _ = []
```