# Patching a recursively-defined list without a <<loop>>

Tags: haskell, tying-the-knot

## Context

We all know [the recursively-defined Fibonacci sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6273621/12274):

```
fibs = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)

λ> fibs
[1,1,2,3,5,9,13,21,34,55,89...
```

## Question

I'm trying to “patch” it in a few places, so that:

1. the general recursive equation “element is sum of two previous elements” holds, but
2. there can be countable exceptions as to individual elements' values.

## Where I'm at

### Utility

To this end, I'll define the following function to modify a specific element in a list:

```
patch :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
patch i v xs = left ++ v : right where (left,_:right) = splitAt i xs
```

I can use it to change the sequence of naturals:

```
λ> patch 5 0 [0..]
[0,1,2,3,4,0,6,7,8,9...
```

### Post-patch

So far, so good. Now to patch the Fibonacci sequence:

```
λ> patch 1 0 fibs
[1,0,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89...
```

This fulfills requirement (2).

### Full patch

To get (1) as well, I'll rewrite the definition in a more explicit tie-the-knot style:

```
fibs' p = rec where rec = p (1 : 1 : zipWith (+) rec (tail rec))
```

With no patch, it still works as expected:

```
λ> fibs' id
[1,1,2,3,5,9,13,21,34,55,89...
```

And I now can patch the element I want and keep the recursive definition:

```
λ> fibs' (patch 1 0)
[1,0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34...
```

### Limitation

But can I?

```
λ> fibs' (patch 5 0)
<<loop>>
```

## Problem

What's wrong?

Intuitively, the dataflow seems sound.  Every list element ought to have a proper definition that does not involve loops.  I mean, it was good enough for no-patch `fibs`; the patching only ought to make it *more* defined.

So I'm probably missing something.  Some strictness issue with my `patch` function?  Some strictness issue elsewhere?  Something else entirely?

Comment: My real problem is way more involved, but when splitting it down to subproblems I couldn't even get this part right, so here we are. I'll definitely have one or more questions pending. At any rate: my core function is certainly not `(+)`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're a bit stricter than you mean to be. Look at

```
patch i v xs = left ++ v : right where (left,_:right) = splitAt i xs
```

I believe you intend that `xs` is guaranteed to have at least `i` elements. But `splitAt` doesn't know that. You can likely fix your program using your own splitter.

```
splitAtGuaranteed :: Int -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
splitAtGuaranteed 0 xs = ([], xs)
splitAtGuaranteed n ~(x:xs) = first (x :) $ splitAtGuaranteed (n - 1) xs
```

#### Edit

Daniel Wagner points out that you don't need all the laziness (or the partiality) of `splitAtGuaranteed`. It's enough to be just a tiny bit lazier:

```
patch i v xs = left ++ [v] ++ drop 1 right where (left, right) = splitAt i xs
```

Comment: Good find. Instead of rewriting `splitAt`, making the pattern lazier (as in `(left,~(_:right)) = splitAt i xs`) appears to be sufficient.

Comment: @DanielWagner, I didn't actually do any testing, so I took the conservative route ;-).

Comment: (Another possibility is to use only total functions and pattern matches which are guaranteed to suceed, as in `patch i v xs = left ++ [v] ++ drop 1 right where (left, right) = splitAt i xs`.)

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!  I'd have two minor subquestions.  Any difference/intent behind that `a++[b]++c` instead of my `a++b:c`? Any meaningful difference between those `drop 1` and a simple `tail`?

Comment: `a++b:c` is just as good (better without optimization). I was just copying from Daniel's comment. `drop 1` has the advantage of being a total function. `drop 1 [] = []` while `tail []` is an error.

Comment: @JB. I find the symmetry of `a++[b]++c` pleasing; in most cases, it is also closer to the "intent" that I have in my head than `a++b:c` is. Since GHC is well smart enough to turn `a++[b]++c` into the more efficient `a++b:c` on its own, these aesthetics win out over the only technical consideration that differentiates them.